# Windows 10 Feature Upgrades without Rebooting

Tags: windows, windows-10

There are a lot of scripts out there to do Windows 10 Feature Upgrades but none of them I have found do it without a forced reboot when finished. If you do the Feature Upgrade via Windows Updates it does not do a forced reboot when finished. It waits for the user to reboot.

The problem is that if you do it remotely to a computer and that user has things opened and walks away from his/her desk it will reboot and crash the things they have opened.

If you do the Feature Update from the CD you can use the /noreboot option. So has anyone come up with a script that will do the feature update without a forced reboot at the end?

Comment: Change settings to restart in off hours. Works.

Comment: Not really what I am looking for. Looking for a script that will do the upgrade but not reboot.

Comment: No such thing, really. All programs that need a restart must be restarted at some point, or:  (1) the upgrade will not take effect and (2) nothing else can normally be installed or upgraded.

Comment: Which feature update exactly are you trying to upgrade to? The last three feature updates have been enabled through enablement packages, and while they do require a reboot, they are as quick as any other Windows Update. It’s impossible to avoid at least one reboot.

Comment: Are you asking if a major Windows update can be installed completely without the computer being restarted at all, or just if there's a script or method to install the update except for the restart, which will then occur at a later time or at the user's choosing?

Comment: Windows locks files by default so without rebooting many files can't be replaced/updated. It's unlike \*nix where the replacement will succeed but the running apps will continue to use the old version until restarted

Answer (score 0):

> If you do the Feature Upgrade via Windows Updates it does not do a
> forced reboot when finished. It waits for the user to reboot.

Normally an update will occur in Off Hours if this has been set. I use this for customers and (a) it works and (b) it alleviates Update Stress.

Have the user set both Pause Updates and have them pick a date that is convenient.

Have the user set Working Hours so that Updates are done in Off Hours. This is always on (effective) once set.

So Manage Updates and they will be less problematic.

By the way there was a big update yesterday and a follow up .NET update just now. Windows is telling me I must restart.  I am simply ignoring this until I save my work. I never lose anything to updates.

I have tested all of this.

[image: Pause Updates]

.

[image: Set Working Hours]

Comment: With certain settings, Windows will also reopen the programs and files the user previously had open, even across updates, making this even less of an issue.

Comment: Agreed. That is also possible to do with newer versions of Windows 10.